# How to stream v380 wifi cam video in my own android app, not using their own application?

Tags: android, video, camera, stream, wifi

I have a v380 wifi cam. I need to get the video it is streaming in my own android app not using their provided application on play store. I can't find out what protocol they are using to transmit the video. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

They are probably using RTSP (Real Time Streaming Protocol) hope that helps a bit